# Adding confirmation action dialog before changing selected Action Tab?

Tags: java, android, tabs, actionbarsherlock, android-alertdialog

I am trying to ask the user to confirm (via AlertDialog) that they want to switch Tabs, before the new tab is selected. I am using the ActionBarSherlock library (since I want to compile in Android 2.3 and later) to create Action Tabs in my Android Layout, and can see when a new Tab is selected, and unselected. Currently, I use this to know when to ask the user to confirm the switch like such:

```
    ActionBar ab;
    String newTab;

    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    ab = getSupportActionBar();
    newTab=tab.getText().toString();

    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Continue?")
    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to continue?")
    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            // User confirms that they want to switch tabs
            if (newTab.equals("tab 1")) {
                setContentView(R.layout.tab1);
            } else if (newTab.equals("tab 2")) {
                setContentView(R.layout.tab2);
            } 
        }
     })
    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            // DONT switch tabs
            ab.selectTab(prevTab);
        }
     })
    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
    .show();

    // update the previous tab
    prevTab = ab.getSelectedTab();
    }
```

However, if the user wants to select "No" (dont switch tabs), the library seems to have already selected it? Is it possible to control what happens before the library selects this new tab, and subsequently ask for user confirmation before actually switching?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

using the setContentView () command do not think the best solution to your problem. I suggest using the TabHost.

Edit:

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.example.teszt;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TabHost;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TabHost tabs;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

        tabs = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
        tabs.setup();

        TabHost.TabSpec Favorit = tabs.newTabSpec("Favorit");
        Favorit.setContent(R.id.favorite);
        Favorit.setIndicator((Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 10) ? "Favorit" : "");
        tabs.addTab(Favorit);

        TabHost.TabSpec All_line = tabs.newTabSpec("All");
        All_line.setContent(R.id.all);
        All_line.setIndicator((Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 10) ? "All" : "");
        tabs.addTab(All_line);

        for(int i = 0; i < tabs.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); ++i){
            tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ShowDialog();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void ShowDialog(){
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            alertDialog.setTitle("Continue?");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to continue?");
            alertDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if(tabs.getCurrentTab() == 0){
                        tabs.setCurrentTab(1);
                    }else{
                        tabs.setCurrentTab(0);
                    }
                }
            });
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Do nothing
                }
            });
            alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
            alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

**framgment_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@+id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:paddingTop="48dp" >

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/favorite"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="tab1" />

            </TableLayout>

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/all"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="tab2" />

            </TableLayout>

        </FrameLayout>

    </TabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

I hope I could help!

Comment: Thanks! However, can TabHosts be implemented in Android 2.3 (this is what I am trying to compile in)? Instead is it possible to do this same thing using ActionBarSherlock?